How to keep meat in a dungeon fresh, preserved, and hot?
I'm making a universe where game tropes are justified. One of them is dungeon food. In many videogames, the protagonist can find meat behind breakable walls and all sorts of random areas. This food is always edible, never goes bad, and is in a great, hot condition. Pests also never reach and eat the meat for some reason. This is despite the fact that the meat is almost never found in an oven or refrigerator.
The setting is 1800s Europe. There are a bunch of old castles around and the owners decide to store meat in random places. How can they keep the meat in good condition so that when the protagonist comes storming through, they can eat the food they find without worry.

How much wiggle room do we have? You're basically asking us to crowbar science into a nonsensical fantasy trope - which obviously isn't going to work directly. Heat changes things, like causing the meat to eventually turn into a form of carbon and causing trouble with the fresh apple that's supposed to be refrigerated. SciFi has long enjoyed using (e.g.) self-heating pre-packaged containers. What are our limits?

We aren't a brainstorming site. Don't just toss us problems and ask us to create solutions for you. That's the equivalent of asking on SO for us to write a program for you. Instead show us a specific scope limited problem that you cannot solve on yourself. What's the minimum reproduceable form of that problem with all the extraneous details removed.

If you kill all the bacteria in a steak and shrink wrap it in plastic it would keep for a long time at room temperature. Or, you know, because magic.

Food preservation is easily one of the most sought after technologies historically. The best answers to your question will all be real historic techniques from that era, like pickling or fermenting.

hot is your deal breaker you can't keep meat hot and edible for long. cold and edible is doable. hot has to be just magic. smoked and salted meat can last a long time.

Err climate? Try storing meat long term in a dungeon in 17th century England or (northern) France for example and your in for a world of hurt (and food poisoning). Try storing it in a climate that is usually/completely hot and dry? You may have a chance, although the hero who discovers this 'hoard' of meat is going to have to soak it in water for a few hours before it's even edible.

The hard part will be explaining how shoving a whole roast chicken down your throat can instantly heal even the most severe near-fatal wounds.

The food is kept hot by dragons in chains behind the wall.

DUNGEON MESHI! Wait, that's not what you wanted?

Meat is freshest when alive. Whether it's hot depends on the physical features!

Can you say what you actually hope to achieve?
The dungeon might present difficulties and how could those matter more than the simple impossibility of keeping anything, anywhere, fresh, preserved, and hot at the same time?
If it's fresh, it's neither preserved nor hot.
If it's preserved, it's neither fresh nor hot.
If it's hot, it's neither preserved nor fresh.
How could your dungeon affect any of that?

It tastes like fresh meat because it is fresh meat.
"Home is where the hearth is" is as true for orcs, goblins, and kobolds as is is for humans... and while a dungeon may not be much to look it, for these guys, it is home.  Monsters work hard for their food, and despite their reputation, most of them would rather hide than fight you over it. So, as soon as they hear someone coming, their first instinct will be to try to hide their food to keep it from being stolen: that includes the nice fresh turkey leg that they were planning on eating soon. So, they stash it away in urns or lock it up in chests, etc.
Many smaller or sneakier monsters may even put out their fires to hide or slip away into hidden rooms that are blocked off too something big and clumsy like an adventurer.  So when you slash your way through a dungeon full of undead that don't eat, only to find an urn or hidden room with fresh meat in it, the detail that you are missing is all the little goblinoids who live in this dungeon, but would rather not fight you; so, all those poor little guys are just cowering under the floorboards or in their other secret hiding spots trying not to sob too loudly while they watch you cluelessly eat the dinner that they just worked so hard on.
And because most goblinoids are carnivores, it means that they are constantly either hunting or cooking meat; so, odds are that when you enter a dungeon containing several packs of goblinoids that at least one or two of them will be just so happen to be cooking their latest meal, or at least have some fresh leftovers they were planning to save for latter.

You made me feel guilty remembering my many hours cleaning dungeons in Skyrim. How many goblins did I leave poor and hungy?

@MickaëlC.Guimarães All of them.  ;)

The obvious method to accomplish something in a medieval setting that is only hit-or-miss in the 21st century is magic.
The alternative is to have a "living" dungeon, where various denizens consume food and replace it with fresh on a routine basis, just as you do with your home cupboards and refrigerator.  A well-house can keep cool things cool (around 50F in a north temperate climate), which works for most cheeses and butter, though milk will keep for only a few days at that temperature.  Eggs, of course, if not washed and bleached as they are in America, can keep for weeks at room temperature.  Meats can be preserved by pouring melted tallow or lard to cover the meat; this will keep fresh meat good for weeks, and cured meats (ham or bacon, for instance) for much longer.
And of course, dry goods like meal, flour, dry beans, or white rice, as well as intentionally dried food like ship's biscuit, jerky, and pemmican, will keep for a very long time, with moisture and rodents being the primary cause of spoilage (and both preventable with suitable packaging).

reminds me of " dungeon no naka no hito " serie

The perpetual stew
You don't even need 19th century technology, it was available in the middle ages.
The drawback is that it has to be some kind of stew, it won't work with solid food.
It just needs a constant source of fuel, as it has to keep cooking perpetually. You can solve that mechanically, as well as stirring it to keep it from burning. Then it is edible even after decades or more.
To make it even more realistic and to have some justification for why it's there, it could be used to feed the guards, they eat a little from the pot and then add ingredients to fill it up again. But it stays the same stew.

Smoking
Best we have is smoked and cured meat, kept somewhat warm. But not hot, more later.
Curing meat is available with that tech, just make sure to do it properly.
Using pork or beef would be better than stuff like chicken.
There are many variables but I think with such setups we are looking at a 1 year and longer.
Smoking is super easy and does not require advanced tech.
This video might be useful.
Basically your lord would have a little area to smoke the meat.
First you salt it to remove more water.
And once you have a fire do not put it directly on it. Btw the type of wood impacts the taste.
In the smoking area you light the fire and make sure that the smoke is directed towards the meat.
Smoke it slowly in lower temperatures, since your lord does not have the ability to know the temp just make sure it's not hot enough to cook, for several days
Once done, let it air dry for a while to finish the process.
You can then place them in sealed pots or whatever. But you can't have them be hot, as that will cook them and begin the spoiling process.
However this does have a finite shelf life, which largely depends on many variables we can't account for.
Maybe your lord donates the foods he has at the end of every year, and restocks the dungeons. Maybe the story's economy is hilariously built around that. Like your world has whole industries around maintaining death traps, refilling foods and drinks in dungeons, restocking the scorpions pit, fixing stuff that the hero breaks as they walk through town...etc.
I dunno if it fits your tone. So. Take this with some curation, sorry I could not resist.
Other more plausible alternatives
Hardtack, Pemmican, honey, and alcohol.
Hardtack
Hardtack, sometimes called ship biscuits, is a real thing and low enough tech that it goes back thousands of years.
Shelf life is anything from few years to decades. it's as super simple mix of water flour, sometimes salt, then baked for a while.
You can also fortify them with stuff like grounded nuts or dried fruits, but that reduces the shelf life.
Please notice that the hard part is real. It is not something you can just eat. You have to soften up before trying to eat. That's why I'm suggesting drinks with it. Your adventure can soak them in the stuff found in the dungeon for a very accurate realistic and replenishing meal. Also hilarious that your adventure just sets up a meal in the dungeon and waits like 10 minutes for the food to get soft enough.
Maybe have them practice a skill or something, but I digress.
Pemmican
Super simple food made of tallow, dried meat, and sometimes dried berries.
Historical food within the time period. And some reports say it lasts up to 10 or more years.
There are many other videos, those two give you a rough idea on it.
Townsends video 1
Townsends video 2
Honey.
Pots of honey found in Egypt that are 3000+ years old were found to be safe to consume. You just have to store it properly.
Alcohol
Alcohol is also an obvious choice. It can last for decades and even centuries if stored properly. Whiskey, rum and some wines would be excellent choices.
All in all, if you just remove the hot part then you can have long lasting foods in dungeons easily

Sidenote about hardtack is that it was specifically meant to be eaten when soldiers did not have time to stop and properly set up camp.  While it did have to be eaten with water, you did not have to stop to do it.  It was most of often eaten while on the march with the hardtack in one hand and a canteen in the other.

The wall is alive, as in, what looks like brick, is actually the skin of a giant worm- which boils a part of from itself if it feels an attack. First is a thorough local fever,next a chemical burn, finally a fire from oils ejected by the tissue next to it. Roasted and juicy..
Bonus round: Enemies sinking into the ground, are actually eaten by the dungeon wyrm. To colonize the assbyss beneath the town, one must be hard, and steadfast of heart, also of stomache and dont forget the bbq sauce.
PS: All this has lead to local stories of the "cellar of infinite feasts" - and the heroe is not the only one who dwells there- other creatures of fire found the idea of meaty walls tempting.
Dragons roast the wyrm and eat it from the inside, growing tremendous in size,  leaving behind only ashcrusted rock walls.

This is impossible today, much less in the 1800s
We can't do what you're asking for today. As I mentioned in my comment, heat changes things. Even keeping a slab of steak warm continues to cook it. There is no way to have the stake both hot and "preserved" such that it's edible medium-rare for any length of time measured beyond minutes. Maybe an hour. After that it becomes medium, then medium-well, then well-done... and eventually it's a burnt pile of carbon. Heat is an active time-based process that humanity cannot stop without Clarkean Magic that stops time in a limited area.
Your protagonist's only option is to head for the kitchen, where they'll find a cauldron of stew. In that era (well... earlier, but let's stretch history a bit), the pot was frequently added to with whatever people had available for days before actually emptying and cleaning the pot. Was this a sanitation hazard? Absolutely! But people back then didn't suffer the susceptibility to disease that we suffer today for washing too frequently. Then again, when we get sick we tend not to die from it, so it's a fair trade.
Anyway, that fact about the pot of stew was common enough to lead to the English nursery rhyme "Pease Porridge Hot."
Just to make things worse, things go rotten over time. We can preserve by smoking or with salt (or a number of other methods) but even that's not magic. Place a piece of smoked and dried salmon in what amounts to a stone box and it'll go moldy eventually.
There are a few cases of very old edible foods (including possibly edible neolithic bread). But none of it was hot. Still, you might use the conditions of these finds as a means of rationalizing nutritious long-term-storage food.
But if you're looking for the 1800s scientifically-viable equivalent of an Automat, that's impossible.

There are restaurants in the Far East where soup cauldrons have been kept simmering, with new ingredients and water added as needed, for literally decades.  As long as the temperature is kept "hot" (above 140 F is the usual criterion) this is bacteriologically safe.  If there's enough turnover, nothing in the pot is acutally more than a few days old -- but the "soup" might be forty years or older as a continuing construct.  Think of it as Theseus Stew...

@ZeissIkon That's either uber cool or incredibly gross! I'm still debating which, but that's a great point to make. Thanks!

@ZeissIkon --- The meat is almost never found in an oven or refrigerator. This would almost always preclude dungeon explorers coming across pots of Uncle Zonks Century Stew.

Preservatives
I'll skip the 'hot' portion in general, as that is something I haven't experienced myself.
Food has been scarce in many instances throughout history for humans. Even so they survived long, hash winters. Crops failing. Voyages at sea that take months. The short and easy of it is this. Pick the right food, or preserve it.
Many types of food preserve themselves. Think of potatoes or beans. Many if them are well preserved for so long as they need to stay good throughout a winter before growing again. These can be found in spades in your setting. With some techniques they can be relatively pest free. Think staunch barrels, or having a cat. These are a great way to start having good food behind a wall. I'll not guarantee all are good, though maybe the game conveniently skips showing those and just the perfect potato.
Next are preservatives. You've definitely had these in your lifetime. It is food prepped to ward off most things, yet are edible by humans. Salt and sugar are great examples. Thanks to osmosis they generally suck bacteria dry. Larger creatures need to have enough mass or special biology to even try to eat so much sugars or salt. Honey is a natural example of this, being eaten only by a select few. Salted pork, or sweets last. Other methods include alcohol and oil.
It is also a great practice to remove things for preserving. Drying food greatly improves the longevity. Think of tomatoes. They rot much more quickly if they aren't dried. Drop them into salt or oil after for extra bonus points.
There is also the creation of many foods that get longevity. Many cheeses have an incredible shelf life. Some are even intentionally left to rot with a human edible fungus that keeps away many other organisms.
With these methods you can create full, succulent meals for any adventurers that ransack secret rooms in a castle.
Mundane reasons
If you want a full hot meal the reason can be very simple. People need to eat. Paul just received his hot cooked chicken with potatoes. He came out of his secret room to check what the ruckus was about. He god absolutely destroyed by the hero, who proceeds to knock down the wall instead of using the secret door and finds a hot meal. Great to put on the other 3 in his magic backpack in case he needs to eat it along with 10 wheels of cheese in an epic battle.

It's filling yet radioactive.
The meat is stored above a strong source of radiation.

That keeps it hot (since radioactive materials emit heat),
keeps it from rotting (radiation kills microorganisms)
and also adds that mysterious treasure-like glow video game secrets often have.

Add in a water drip to keep it from drying, and you are set for N+1 half-lives.
DISCLAIMER:

Health issues after eating too much dungeon manga meat are not related to consuming dungeon manga meat. It must be all the miasma in the air. If your hair is falling after delving our dungeon, it's because you got cursed by the BBEG in his death throes.


Alive
The meat is fresh, preserved, and still warm because it's still alive ("on the hoof") and yet to be slaughtered and prepared by monsters or PCs. Consider it something like a wet market in the dungeon. Some iterations might be:

Pig pens
Cattle stalls
Chicken coops
Fish ponds or tanks

Etc.

Make cold-blooded lizard-person adventurers and populate the castles with grain stores, rats, and cats. (The cats keep the rat population from getting too big and resulting in sub-par rats.)
Hot (compared to cold-blooded lizard people), kept fresh by healthy immune systems, and in great condition. You've never seen such handsome, well-fed rats and cats. Delicious.

Iron Rations
Traditionally, Dungeons & Dragons uses the term "iron ration" in a somewhat mixed-up way, as something like beef jerky, hardtack, and dried fruit.
But the term actually comes from the WWI development of armies giving soldiers an emergency supply of food in their packs, notably with the meat packed in an early tin can. For example, you can read more at the Sir John Monash Center Australian National Memorial site.

The name ‘Iron Ration’ came from the tinned, boiled beef to
distinguish the emergency supplies from fresh rations. Australians
adapted the French term ‘bouilli beef’ to ‘bully beef’.

On the one hand, tin-can technology wasn't really available in the medieval-technology world. But in my fantasy campaign I assert that dwarves have this knowledge, and so canned, long-lasting meats can be in the world at somewhat higher cost.
Note that e.g. modern canned hams can be stable for 2-5 years, per the USDA food safety site under the "canned hams" question.
So tin-can/iron-ration technology gets you fresh and preserved, if not hot out of the can. Current NATO requirements, for example, are that packaged rations must be consumable without heat. But if you want it hot you need to provide that yourself.
